# Get path for every file python loads when importing modules

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to make a directory containing all the modules a python script depends on. Rather than manually tracking down all those files, I would like to automatically find these files as python imports them. To do this, I've added a module finder to `sys.meta_path`:

```
import sys, imp
class ImportPrint(object):
    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        toks = name.split(".")
        pre, loc = ".".join(toks[:-1]), toks[-1]
        try: 
            module_info = imp.find_module(loc, path)
        except ImportError:
            module_info = imp.find_module(loc)
        if module_info[0]: module_info[0].close
        print "A", name, module_info[1]
        return None
sys.meta_path = [ImportPrint()]

import mymod1, mymod2, etc..
```

This almost works, but the `__init__.py` files are not found this way. Is there a better way to find them, or should I just hackily add them whenever the file found is a directory? Will this method miss any other files.

Comment: You could use inspect to locate each module and find out which ones are located in packages.

Comment: @Kupiakos: That sounds interesting. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for sys.meta_path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path), your `find_module` method will be called with the `path` argument set to the path of a package if it is one. Why not use `os.path.join(path, '__init__.py')` for when `path` exists?